# Hive - Output multiple files per partition

Tags: hive, compression, partition

I am trying to generate a set of compressed csv files that I can be picked up and processed by a spark script running on a cluster.  As such, I want the data to be split into multiple pieces so that the downstream processing can be parallelized across the nodes of the cluster.  Currently, no matter what options I have set, hive outputs a single large file ~1GB per partition.  This significantly slows down the later operations in spark.  How can I set it so that hive creates multiple smaller files instead of a single large one?

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS model_sample (
<fields>
)
partitioned by (market string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3://...';

set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
set hive.exec.compress.output=true;
set mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec;

set hive.merge.tezfiles=false;
set hive.merge.mapfiles=false;
set hive.merge.mapredfiles=false;
set mapred.max.split.size=68157440;
set mapred.min.split.size=68157440;
set hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=128000000;

insert overwrite table model_sample partition(market)(
    select * from ...
);
```

Comment: You don't need Hive for that, you can simply read your data with Spark

Comment: Splits are made by Spark, so I am not really sure what you are talking about. Are you?